# Using `transform` parameter for `Axes.inset_axes` in matplotlib correctly

Tags: matplotlib

I want to add a subplot inside my main plot and control very precisely its position and its orientation. Here is my attempt before trying to rotate the second axis:

```
import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

fig = plt.figure()

main_axis = fig.add_subplot()
main_axis.set_aspect('equal')
main_axis.set(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-1, 1))

scat_axis = main_axis.inset_axes([0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
scat_axis.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

The result that I am obtaining is this one:

[image]

But If I try to rotate the second one using `transform` parameter for `Axes.inset_axes`, the graph is disappearing. Even if the transformation that i am adding is the identity (like this: `rotation = Affine2D()`)

```
import matplotlib, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

fig = plt.figure()

main_axis = fig.add_subplot()
main_axis.set_aspect('equal')
main_axis.set(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-1, 1))

rotation = Affine2D().rotate_deg(45)
scat_axis = main_axis.inset_axes([0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5], transform=rotation)
scat_axis.set_aspect('equal')

plt.show()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The transform argument really only applies to the position of the axes, so it cannot create a rotation unfortunately.  It is not an extra transform applied to everything inside the axes.

Comment: It explains everything, thank you. Do you know if there is a way to rotate my inset axis?

Comment: Perhaps https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html?